# Data column(s) for axis #0 cannot be of type string Error with Javascript

Tags: javascript, charts, google-visualization

When I am try to create my own chart with google charts library, it is giving to me `Data column(s) for axis #0 cannot be of type string error.`

I am receiving data with http request with Ajax library. And I created the array like;

```
    0: (2) ["Time", "Value"]
    1: (2) ["Tue Nov 05 2019 00:00:00 GMT+0300 (GMT+03:00)", 49.4638863]
    2: (2) ["Tue Nov 05 2019 01:00:00 GMT+0300 (GMT+03:00)", 73.19763]
    3: (2) ["Tue Nov 05 2019 02:00:00 GMT+0300 (GMT+03:00)", 91.66373]
```

When I check the examples and documents, my array type looks true.

```js
    google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['corechart']});
    google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

    var endpoint = "http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/api"
    var chartData = [["Time", "Value"]];
    console.log(typeof chartData)
    $.ajax({
    method: "GET",
    url: endpoint,
    success: function(data){
    var valueData = data;
    for(i = 0; i< data.length; i++){
        //console.log("Time Data: ", data[i].time)
        chartData.push([String(new Date(data[i].time)), Number(data[i].value)]);
        }
        //console.log("Chart Data: ", chartData);
    },
    error: function(error_data){
        console.log("error")
        console.log(error_data)
        }
    });

    function drawChart() {
        console.log(chartData)
    var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
        chartData
    ]);

    var options = {
        title: 'Tag Value',
        curveType: 'function',
        legend: { position: 'bottom' }
    };

    var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('curve_chart'));

    chart.draw(data, options);
    }
```

chartData is;

```
    0: (2) ["Time", "Value"]
    1: (2) ["Tue Nov 05 2019 00:00:00 GMT+0300 (GMT+03:00)", 49.4638863]
    2: (2) ["Tue Nov 05 2019 01:00:00 GMT+0300 (GMT+03:00)", 73.19763]
    3: (2) ["Tue Nov 05 2019 02:00:00 GMT+0300 (GMT+03:00)", 91.66373]
    4: (2) ["Tue Nov 05 2019 03:00:00 GMT+0300 (GMT+03:00)", 98.4258347]
```

What should I do for push my array to google chart without this error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

need to remove the extra brackets, here...

```
var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(chartData);
```

`arrayToDataTable` takes an array of arrays, which you're creating here...

```
var chartData = [["Time", "Value"]];
```

add appending to here...

```
chartData.push([String(new Date(data[i].time)), Number(data[i].value)]);
```

currently, you end up with...

```
[[["Time", "Value"],[...],[...]]]
```

note: given the format of your data, no need to cast the types here...

```
chartData.push([new Date(data[i].time), data[i].value]);
```